How to upload files with flightphp
Please give me a example to upload files in flightphp framework. i coded as ...
Flight::route('POST /regSubTask', function () {
 $request = Flight::request();
 $file = $request->files['imagefile']; 
 var_dump($file);
});

But return as null
$file = Flight::request()->data['imagefile'];

this one return name only

From the Flight Docs page, here's how you access it as you've already tried:
$uploadedFile = Flight::request()->files['myFile'];

In this example, $uploadedFile is basically just like $_FILES['myFile']. So the example in the PHP docs would actually work in this case as well.
<?php
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($uploadedFile["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $uploadedFile["tmp_name"][$key];
        // basename() may prevent filesystem traversal attacks;
        // further validation/sanitation of the filename may be appropriate
        $name = basename($uploadedFile["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
?>

As of right now, Flight doesn't have a built in way to handle file uploads, but I'll make a note of it for a future feature (I currently maintain Flight).

Thanks for your cooperation.. I will try this.

I added a new release for flight that handles file uploads in a simpler way. https://github.com/flightphp/core/releases/tag/v3.12.0
